# When passing custom and standard picklist value in url it is showing as null

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am passing custom and standard picklist values in url as a parameters but it is always showing as null in url.

This page is used to create Opportunity, before creating Opportunity when a button is clicked I am redirecting to other VF page and then after performing some action on that page I want to comeback to the same page  without loosing values that I entered first (like stage and custom picklist).

**Controller** :

```
 public class controller_class {
    Public string custompicklist{ get; set; }
    public string stageParam {get;set;}
    public string customparam;
    Opportunity cur_record;
    public controller_class(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

     cur_record = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();

      stageparam= Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get(stageParam);
      customparam = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get(customparam);

                }
     public PageReference redirect()
        {
     PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/Vfpage?stageparam='+cur_record.StageName+'&customparam='+cur_record.custompick__c); 
    // in url it is showing as stageparam=null&customparam=null 
    return pr;
            }
 public List<SelectOption> getpicks()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('one','one'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('two','two'));
       return options;
    }

    }
```

VF page :

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!OppString.StageName }" required="true" />
 <apex:outputPanel >

  <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!custompicklist}">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!picks}"/>
  </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: What is the URL used to load the page. How to you get to the redirect method

Answer (score 1):

Fields are not pulled into the sObject obtained using getRecord unless they are present on the VF page or explicitly added using `addFields`. You have not shown your VF page or the URL used to initially load the page so the following is a best guess as to why those values are returning null.

You have three options:

1. Output the `stageName` and `custompick__c` fields on the page. You can even use an input hidden. This will query for the values when the page is loaded
2. Use the [addFields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm) method of the standardController prior to calling `getRecord` - beware though that you must bypass addFields in test methods by checking `isRunningTest()` - in you test when instantiating the apex class pass in the sObject with those fields queried
3. Query for the sObject in your method and use the values

If you could also post the URL you are hitting to load the page the first time that would be great. It must have an `id` parameter for your code to work

Comment: Good one Eric... diving into (addFields)